# Python 2.7.3: if statements not working within a function

Tags: python, function

Having a problem here with trying to add if statements to a function I am defining. To put things in context, I am programming a Black Jack simulation for a school project.

Here's what I'm having trouble with:

```
def getDecision():
    getDecision = raw_input("What will you do? \n - Hit \n - Stand")
    if getDecision = "Hit": 
        return hit()
```

I want it so that I can set two conditions in the function when it is called in main: if the player selects Hit, it returns the function hit in which the player receives a card. If the player selects Stand, the turn will transfer to the opponent (CPU).

What do I have to do to fix this? I get a syntax error on my if statement.

And here is the rest of the program as of now if you wish to scrutinize:

```
import random
def showMenu():
    userInput = raw_input("Welcome to the game of Black Jack! Please choose an option from the following: \n - Start Game \n - Rules \n - Exit")

def getInitialMoney():
    initialdough = 5000

def cardGenerator():
#Assign a random suit
    suit_card = ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamond"]
    from random import choice
#Assign a random number between 1-13 (Ace to King)
    number_card = random.randrange(1,14)
    print choice(suit_card), str(number_card)

def getPlayerCards():
    return cardGenerator(), cardGenerator()

def getCPUcards():
    return cardGenerator(), cardGenerator()
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` checks equality.  Different operators.

Comment: If I were you, I'd make a `class Card` and a `class Deck`, and make a method inside `class Deck` that returns a `Card`, removing it from the stub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you are going wrong

```
if getDecision = "Hit":
```

should be

```
if getDecision == "Hit":
```

`=` is assignment and `==` is comparison.

This is how your final code should look like

```
def getDecision():
getDecision = raw_input("What will you do? \n - Hit \n - Stand")
if getDecision == "Hit": 
    return hit()
```

Comment: woops, can't believe I didn't notice that. It's been a while since I last worked on python in school ^_^;; slacking off